# Can Views be used to limit access to certain metrics?

Tags: google-analytics

Can Google Analytics Views be used to restrict access to metrics and dimensions?  Is there anyway this can be accomplished?

Say I wanted to create a view and share it with someone else.  I want the view to only have access to Pageviews and Sessions over time.  I would want to restrict access to more sensitive dimensions such as referring sites.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, but as a workaround you can create a custom report and schedule it to be sent via e-mail. Not quite on-topic, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share the view, the user will have access to all dimensions and metrics. There is no way to restrict it

Comment: Kind of figured this was the case reading throughout the internet.  But wanted to make sure.  Thank you for re-assurance.